# Is there any way to stop the Windows 10 Clipboard Manager from automatically pasting selected items?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard

If I select an item from the Clipboard Manager history, then I'd like that item to be placed on the clipboard, but not subsequently automatically pasted into the document / edit field. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> but not automatically pasted. Is this possible?

No. With the current implementation of Clipboard Management history in Windows 10 and 11, the item selected automatically goes on the clipboard.

That is by design.

I checked with the newest version of Microsoft Power Toys and it does not change Windows Clipboard functionality.

You would need a third party clipboard manager.

I use and am happy with the Windows Clipboard system.

Comment: I Have edited the question for clarity. To be clear, I am happy for the item to go onto the clipboard. It is the subsequent automatic pasting into the document / edit field that I would prefer to not happen.

Comment: @TechHorse - I am unable to reproduce the automatic pasting of something I copied, are you certain, this isn’t specific to your system?

Comment: It may depend on a system, but here it is always automatic pasting.